# Why does Lubuntu-Installer does not find eMMC Disk

Tags: lubuntu, emmc

Im trying to install Lubuntu 18.4 (in the meantime I have also tried Lubuntu 20.4) on a brand new Laptop (HP Notebook 14s-fq0918ng)

The Lubuntu installer (and of course also the live version) does not recognize the drive (eMMC) at all. I have already tested various BIOS settings (Secure Boot On/off etc.)
(Incidentally, this laptop does not offer relatively few features in the BIOS)

These two posts in the forum meet my problem very precisely..
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2455173

I would politely ask for quick and specific answers, because if Linux installation on the device is difficult or impossible, I would send the newly purchased device back. However, the deadline is already relatively short here.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Lubuntu has three installers currently supported; and with Lubuntu 20.04 there are two stacks available (GA or the 5.4 kernel & HWE using the 5.8 kernel found on 20.04.2 media), yet you've not been specific as to which you're asking about. Which ISO choice did you make with 18.04? and do you realize it's support ends this month? and it doesn't have an upgrade path without re-install (as it was the last release using LXDE, which requires re-install to switch to LXQt)

Comment: Installing new OS to eMMC disks is a known issue currently. When you buy a laptop that comes with an eMMC, 99% of the time it comes with Windows and the BIOS is locked down when it comes to installing a different operating system. If I recall correctly, the BIOS does something that makes the eMMC not visible (easily anyway) to other OS. There are ways around this, but they are rather dangerous.

Comment: Thanks. For me that sounds its better so send it back.
@guiverc
Im using 18.4 as a frozen System only to use one single programm in full screen mode. The OS will be used in something like kiosk mode and will never be updated.
But thank you for giving feedback to topics that are not asked for here.

Comment: Lubuntu 18.04 was available with two installers (*live* & *alternate*), and the *live* was available with *two stack* choices, but five initial stack choices (18.04 & 18.04.1 used the GA 4.15 kernel, 18.04.2 used 4.18, 18.04.3 used 5.0, 18.04.4 used 5.3, 18.04.5 used 5.4 kernel... so I was asking which you'd tried to install unless by 18.04 you meant the initial 2018-April media without any updates thus initial 4.15 kernel which was all that was available with the *alternate* ISO anyway as it wasn't re-created and *d-i* installer was more limited but it worked with <768MB of RAM)